# Get selected value in flowbite-react Datepicker component - Props change event not working

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, react-props, flowbite

I am having an issue getting the selected value from the [`Datepicker`](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/datepicker) component from the `flowbite-react` library. Using with NextJS.

The component displaying nicely.

I have tried the following code, but return nothing when the date is selected:

```tsx
import { Datepicker } from "flowbite-react";

export default function ExampleComp(){
 return (
   <Datepicker
       onChange={(e) => console.log(e)} // not working
       onSelect={(e) => console.log(e)} // not working
       onInput={(e) => console.log(e)} // not working
       onSelectedDateChanged={(e) => console.log(e)} // Error: Does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatepickerProps'
      />
  )
}
```

Nothing specific use case in the official documentation page but in [`storybook`](https://storybook.flowbite-react.com/?path=/story/components-datepicker--default) there is prop `onSelectedDateChanged`. I'm using it but `Error: Does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatepickerProps`

Kindly help.

version

- "flowbite": "^1.8.1",
- "flowbite-react": "^0.6.0",
- "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
- "next": "13.4.19"

Comment: Experiencing exact the same issue right now! Must be onChange but is doing nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox example of the issue?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Having a similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

onSelectedDateChanged worked for me, passing a function to this props, and getting the required output, using it with react from hook like this

```
<Controller name="date"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: 'Date is required' }}
            render=
            {({ field }) => (
             <Datepicker
              value={field.value}
              onSelectedDateChanged={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
              dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
              className="border rounded px-4 py-2 w-full" />
            )}
          />
```

for regular use you can use useState,and update the date using this.

```
  const handleDatePickerChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
    console.log(date);
  };

<Datepicker name="selectedDate" value={selectedDate}
            onSelectedDateChanged={handleDatePickerChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late but maybe you'll need it.

```
const handleDateChange = (date: Date) => {
   console.log(date);
};

<Datepicker id="date" onSelectedDateChanged={handleDateChange}/>
```

Should work.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    console.log(date);
  };
<Datepicker onSelectedDateChanged={handleDateChange}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**